# is there a way to refactor these two functions? django

Tags: python, django, function, refactoring, reusability

I figured I have been using this quite a lot to render info from a query.  I wonder if there's a way to refactor them?

examples of the codes are

```
def render_objA(self, objAs):
    output = []
    for obj in objAs:
        output.append({
            'id': obj.id,
            'name': obj.name
            'description': obj.description,
            'createdAt': obj.created,
            'modifiedAt': obj.modified
        })
    return output


def render_objB(self, objBs):
    output = []
    for obj in objBs:
        output.append({
            'id': obj.id,
            'name': obj.name,
            'content': obj.content,
            'createdAt': obj.created,
            'modifiedAt': obj.modified
        })
    return output


def render_objC(self, objCs):
    output = []
    for obj in objCs:
        output.append({
            'id': obj.id,
            'first_name': obj.first_name,
            'last_name': obj.last_name,
            'full_name': obj.full_name,
            'createdAt': obj.created,
            'modifiedAt': obj.modified
        })
    return output
```

Some output might have more fields than others and of course different field  name too.  This really depends.

The only similar and for sure fields will be the same is the `createdAt` and `modifiedAt`

Can someone give me an idea or let me know how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should have a method on all of your classes to create the dicts from an object. Then you can use your method on any of your types.

Comment: Never mind refactoring. My question is what is this code supposed to do in the first place? It looks most undjango like. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is better or worst but you can create a key mapping. It may reduce readability but decrease code length.

```
key_mapping = {
    'created': 'createdAt',
    'modified': 'modifiedAt',
}
def create_dic(self, obj, key_list):
    dic = {}
    for k in key_list:
       v = getattr(obj, k, None)
       key = key_mapping.get(k, k)
       if v is not None:
           dic[key] = v
    return dic

def render_objA(self, objAs):
    key_list = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'created', 'modified']
    return [create_dic(obj, key_list) for obj in objAs]

def render_objB(self, objBs):
    key_list = ['id', 'name', 'content', 'created', 'modified']
    return [create_dic(obj, key_list) for obj in objBs]

def render_objC(self, objCs):
    key_list = ['id', 'name', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'full_name', 'created', 'modified']
    return [create_dic(obj, key_list) for obj in objCs]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are trying to render all the fields of an object or not but if you are, you can do something like this. Add this piece of code to the models

```
def __iter__(self):
    for field_name in self._meta.get_all_field_names():
        value = getattr(self, field_name, None)
        yield (field_name, value)
```

and then your render methods would be something like this.

```
def render_obj(self, myobjs):
    output = []
    for obj in myobjs:
        dict = {}
        for field, val in obj:
            dict[field] = val 
        output.append(dict)
    return output
```